# Redux state not updating with javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this container and component and the object `yeast` that Im trying to put in my store. However, its not working whenever I try and save it. The object looks like this

`{ yeastType : value, temp: value}`

**Container.js**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleYeastChange: (yeast) => {
            dispatch(actions.updateYeast(yeast))
        }
    }
};

const RecipeYeastContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(RecipeYeast);
```

**Component.js**

```
updateYeastState = (updatedYeast) => {
    this.props.handleYeastChange(updatedYeast)
};
```

I have no errors in the console or anything. When I open my redux dev tools its telling me the state has already been updated by the time the action is called. And thus only ever saving the first letter thats input into my field. It never persists it. Its really weird. Its also never showing up in the UI. I can type as much as I want and see the action firing and the state keeping the first letter but its not showing up in the input.

Whats weird is that when I change the code to pass in both `yeastType` and `temp` to the property function and construct the object in there it works. (See below)

**This works: Container.js**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleYeastChange: (yeastType, temp) => {
            const yeast = {yeastType, temp}
            dispatch(actions.updateYeast(yeast))
        }
    }
};
```

**Component.js**

```
updateYeastState = (updatedYeast) => {
    this.props.handleYeastChange(updatedYeast.yeastType, updatedYeast.temp)
};
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening. I thought I could just pass the object all the way through and not have to reconstruct it.

Comment: You should debug and compare the prev and next object in redux. When new object changes then only the state will be updated. To debug keep on press F10 you will get into the place where redux compares both object.

Comment: @Ajaykumar Ive tried that. Every keystroke updates the state but only keeps one letter. The UI never updates and when I inspect in chrome, the props on the component never are updating so the value for the input is never updating. Then every keystroke is overwriting the last letter in the state because the UI think thats it. It seems that as long as I reconstruct the `yeast` object somewhere along the reducers path itll save but I cant just pass it through all the way from the component

Answer (score 0):

Do you dispatch your `action` correctly? And in using `redux`, you are not updating the state of the component, you're updating the `store` and then the value in component is from your `mapStateToProps` function that get from the `store`. Say it you're updating your `store` with the object named `yourReducer` store. ex:

Container.js:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  inputValue: state.yourReducer.value
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  inputHandler: (e) => {
    dispatch(yourAction({type: 'CHANGE_INPUT', value: e.target.value}))
    // The store catches the action and pass to the reducer that can read the action's type
    // in `yourReducer` will catch the 'CHANGE_INPUT' type and
    // return a new value as same as the value that passed from the action
  }
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
```

Component.js

```
export default class Component extends React.Component {
  { your custom function here ... }

  render() {
    const { inputValue, inputHandler } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        {/* The input will be the same as the inputValue changed */}
        <input value={inputValue} onChange={inputHandler} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

For debugging `redux` you can try this [redux-devtool](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools).